# О видимой Вселенной(,) или Метагалактике

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, или

Нужна запятая? Если что, видимая Вселенная и Метагалактика — это одно и то же.

> К сожалению, свет до края Вселенной никогда и не дойдëт — из-за расширения Вселенной. Поэтому мы будем в основном говорить только о видимой Вселенной(,) или Метагалактике.

Не моя фраза, ставлю цитирование. Тире перед *из-за* объясняется большой паузой, так что не комментируем этот момент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

*К сожалению, свет до края Вселенной никогда и не дойдёт — из-за расширения Вселенной. Поэтому мы будем в основном говорить только о видимой Вселенной, **или Метагалактике**.*

Союз ***ИЛИ*** — пояснительный.

Сравнить: *Если свет до края Вселенной  никогда не доходит,  то ее можно **назвать** видимой Вселенной **или Метагалактикой**.*

Союз ***ИЛИ*** — разделительный.

**Примечание**

Греческая приставка «мета» означает «над», «сверх», более и так далее, то есть **Метагалактика** – это Сверх– или Супергалактика. Она включает в себя все известные нам космические объекты.

Comment: Спасибо. Метагалактика, или видимая Вселенная, — это та часть Вселенной, которую мы можем увидеть, или 93 млрд световых лет в диаметре. :) За еë пределами остальная часть Вселенной [безусловно, она ещë больше наблюдаемой (видимой) Вселенной, но неизвестно, какого размера].